# What do the type parameters to Source<Out,Mat> mean?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to understand the Source type for Akka streams, specified [here](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html).

Unfortunately, the documentation and examples I've found don't explain what each of the type parameters actually mean. I'm guessing that `Out` is the type that the source emits when materialized. Is that correct? What is the other type parameter `Mat` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Out**

You are correct, this is the type of the elements which are emitted by the `Source`.

**Mat**

It is the type of the `Source`'s materialisation. Note that every stage (`Flow`s, `Sink`s, etc.) will materialise to a value as well.
This is essentially a byproduct of the stage itself **after** it is run.

You can picture it as a mean of interacting with the stage while it's running. Looking at examples of ready-made `Source`s offered by Akka is a good way of getting the gist of it.

- `Source.single` will materialise to `NotUsed`. You got no mean of interacting with the source, as it will produce only one element straightaway and then complete.
- `Source.queue` will materialise to a `SourceQueue`. This is a more interesting case, as you can interact with the source by `offer`ing messages to it. The messages you `offer` will be emitted by the source.
- `Source.maybe` will materialise to a `Promise`. You can use the `Promise` to control the source and make it emit one element, or `None`.

When you concatenate different stages, note that every stage can potentially have a useful materialized value. You get to choose which ones to keep by using `viaMat`/`toMat` and `Keep` DSL.
One or more materialized values will be returned when `run()` is called on the composed graph.

Taking a look at the types in the examples below is the best way to get the gist of the API:

```
  val source: Source[Int, MatSrc]
  val sink: Sink[Int, MatSnk]

  val matSrc: MatSrc = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.left).run()
  val matSnk: MatSnk = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.right).run()
  val (m1: MatSrc, m2: MatSnk) = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()
  val n: NotUsed = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.none).run()
```

Note that the more succinct DSL which you can find in many example is actually a shortcut for the above, where only the materialized value of the last stage (e.g. the sink) is kept.

```
  val mat3: Mat3 = source.viaMat(flow)(Keep.right).toMat(sink)(Keep.right).run()
```

is the same as

```
  val mat3: Mat3 = source.via(flow).runWith(sink)
```

See the docs below for further reading.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/stream/stream-quickstart.html#Materialized_values